# Transformar variavel em string python

Tags: python, string, variáveis

```
fotos = ["C:\dtx\145.jpg", 'C:\dtx\148.jpg]
pyautogui.typewrite(foto)
```

Quando envia o valor da variável para a caixa de dialogo esconde os números e barras, colando apenas o texto puro sem os números e as barras! como faço esta conversão para `str`
já tentei `pyautogui.typewrite(str(foto))` mas da erro também

Comment: Pode ter sido erro de transcrição mas aqui `fotos = ["C:\dtx\145.jpg", 'C:\dtx\148.jpg]` faltou fechar uma aspa `'` em `'C:\dtx\148.jpg'`

Comment: Não resolveria o seu caso `pyautogui.typewrite(" ".join(foto))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve colocar o formatador r na frente da sua string, dessa forma o python vai entender que você quer a string bruta:

```
import pyautogui

fotos = [r'C:\dtx\145.jpg', r'C:\dtx\148.jpg']

for foto in fotos:
    pyautogui.typewrite(foto)
```

Comment: fotos = [r'C:\dtx\145.jpg', r'C:\dtx\148.jpg']

muito obrigada! funcionou perfeitamente, Gratidão!

Só mais uma dúvida se não for abusar muito!


fotos = [r'C:\dtx\145.jpg', r'C:\dtx\148.jpg']

for foto in fotos:
    pyautogui.typewrite(foto)

a cada loop o comando pyautogui.typewrite(foto) envia as duas fotos na lista

teria como a cada loop enviar 1 + 1 ex loop 1 enviar o primeiro item da lista, loop 2 enviar o segundo item e assim por diante!

Comment: @PamelaCardoso, tudo bem? Teoricamente da forma que está seria pra ele escrever 1 foto por iteração. Faz um teste: `for i,foto in enumerate(fotos):
    print(i,foto)`. Dessa forma vai aparecer o número da iteração na frente, por exemplo: 0, 1, 2, 3 e assim por diante, assim você consegue ver qual foto está sendo escrita em cada  iteração. Lembrando que isso é um teste e neste caso eu exclui o comando do pyautogui.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você referencia uma string, você sabe que pode utilizar algumas funções com alguns comandos reservados, e por azar, e da msm forma em que os links de direcionamento se comporta. O **r** indica que sua string vai ser uma '*string bruta*', é assim mesmo e não considera esses **caracteres especiais** que acabei de citar. Sem o r no literal a barra invertida (backslash) faria o que vem a seguir ser considerado um **caractere especial.**

Existe por exemplo o \n, sua função e pular a linha, e quando você encontra um link por exemplo `c:\programs files\note`, note que existe um `\n`, assim, vai dar a intender que vc quer pular a linha e continuar, atividade totalmente fora do contexto se você quer o link completo, onde a forma correta pra essa situação e:

```
nome_da_variavel = r'c:\programs files\note'
```

Assim, ele vai entender que preciso pegar caractere por caractere, desconsiderando as caracteres especiais.
Isso serve pra diversos tipos de caracteres especiais, como #, {} etc...

#Edit:
Complementando, existe tbm uma letra reservada que tem similaridade na funcionalidade. Existem diversas formas de mesclar valores de variaveis dentro da string.
Ex:

```
nome = 'Jose'
print('Meu nome e', nome)
# ou com .format
print('Meu nome e {}'.format(nome))
# e tambem pode ser usado a letra f, de format
print(f'Meu nome e {nome})
```

Ambos codigos resultam em:

```
>>> Meu nome e Jose
```

Com o tempo, treino e estudos você vai descobrindo novas funcionalidades e vai se aprimorando, evoluindo e melhorando a cada passo.

Link referencia: [Clique Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)